# Concatenacion de listas en python

Tags: python

Tengo este problema, en esta lista:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito tranformarlo en algo asi:

> [[6911511697], [3210111532], [1171109732], [9997100101], [11097330]]

Cada grupo es debe quedar de 32bits(es codigo ascii) pues en este ejemplo debería hacer la operación xor a estos bloques, pero como los metí a la lista como si fuera bidimensional ya no supe como acomodarla.
Soy nuevo en el lenguaje pero mi materia lo ocupa muchísimo, gracias por la ayuda..!

Les dejo mi codigo:

```
string = "Esta es una cadena!"
ascii_values = [ord(character) for character in string]
print(ascii_values)

n = 4

out = [(ascii_values[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(string), n)] 

print("Lista sin padding: \n"+str(out))

for obj in out:
    if(len(obj)<4):
       obj.append(0)

 print("Lista con padding: \n"+str(out))
```

Comment: chika tto chika tto chika chika!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Una forma fácil de hacerlo es primero convertir los números a `string` luego concatenarlos y luego convertir el `string` resultante nuevamente a `int`

```
#Lista original, esto sería tu variable out
cadena = [[69,115,116,97], [32,101,115,32], [117,110,97,32], [99,97,100,101], [110,97,33,0]]
#Lista vacía donde crearemos el resultado de la concatenación
resultado = []
#Iteramos en la cadena original para acceder a las sub listas
for obj in cadena:
    #Variable temporal para almacenar el número concatenado como string
    temp = ''
    #Iteramos cada elemento de la sublista actual
    for i in obj:
        #Concatenamos los números como string
        temp += str(i)
    #Salimos del for que itera a la sublista y agregamos el valor de temp a la lista resultado pero como entero
    resultado.append([int(temp)])

print(resultado)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
[[6911511697], [3210111532], [1171109732], [9997100101], [11097330]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Algo más simple

```
# lista original

cadena = [[69,115,116,97], [32,101,115,32], [117,110,97,32], [99,97,100,101], [110,97,33,0]]

# creamos nueva lista

nueva_cadena = [[int(f"{n[0]}{n[1]}{n[2]}{n[3]}")] for n in cadena]
```

Obtenemos al imprimir `nueva_cadena`

```
[[6911511697], [3210111532], [1171109732], [9997100101], [11097330]]
```

Comment: En vez de poner cada uno de los índice puedes usar `slicing` que seria hacer `n[:3]`

Comment: Hola..!! Si me ayudo..!! Pero podrias explicarme como funciona?

Comment: Busca sobre  las "listas por compresión"